# Error with Xcode framework

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I am building a small app using the mapkit framework and I keep getting this error. I have added corelocation, mapkit everything and I have googled everywhere and cant seem to get rid of it.

```
_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView", referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-MKPinAnnotationView in MapViewController.o

Symbol(s) not found
```

and a warning with it says `/MapKit.framework/MapKit, missing required architecture in i386 file`

Ive tried everything from switching to iPhone back to iPad, adding the framework again and nothing is working. I have another small app in which the mapkit works completely fine. I'm just wondering if anyone has seen this error before.

Comment: Have you added both the frameworks and the `import` statement?